# How to get the datetime of a file located inside a folder?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get a datetime of a file which is located inside a folder...
the folder structure is like `dotnet\build\portalFlexLib.swc`

I need to get the datetime of `portalFlexLib.swc` without giving harcore value..

I have tried like this

```
            DateTime ftime = File.GetCreationTime(txtBoxInput.Text);
```

It give only the folder datetime...Any suggestion??

Comment: If the `txtBoxInput.Text` is for the folder, it will give you the folder creation date, and if the text includes the file name it will be for the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could try with FileInfo class?

```
Fileinfo myFileInfo = new Fileinfo(@"C:\path\to\file");
DateTime ftime = myFileInfo.CreationTime;
```

There's the UTC version too;

```
Datetime ftime = myFileInfo.CreationTimeUtc;
```

Comment: Instead of hardcore path i have to give textbox name

Comment: Well bala3569, you can just replace @"C:\path\to\file" with your txtBoxInput.Text (maybe trim() it first? ).

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can do this by file info.

```
    var f= new FileInfo(fileName);
    var creationDate = f.CreationTime;
```

Comment: insert sample of your input.txt, or see it in debug format to check if it's folder name or file name.